# How to test Qt SCXML state machines

Tags: qt, scxml

I'm trying to verify the behavior of a state machine using Qt test framework. I simply don't get how I am supposed to tests Qt SCXML implementation. Sure there is `QSignalSpy`, but that is only for signals/slops which do not require the event loop to run. What I essentially want to do is:

```
myStateMachine.submitEvent("MyEvent");
// Run event loop
// Check result
```

I tried to `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` this sometimes worked, but sometimes also got stuck when calling `processEvents()`. I guess I might triggered an infinite loop. Also googling did not help, but there must be a way to do this properly.

Answer (score 3):

In a QtTest based test you can use `QTest::qWait()` to run the event loop for a given time.

You can also use `QSignalSpy` to wait for a signal to happen within a certain time, see `QSignalSpy::wait()`

If there are more than one signal that can trigger test continuation, you can also use a nested event loop, e.g. something like this

```
QEventLoop loop;
connect(sender1, SIGNAL(signal1()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
connect(sender2, SIGNAL(signal2()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
loop.exec();
```

Potentially combined with a timer to end the loop in case none of those signals arrive

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and we took advantage of [`QScxmlStateMachine::reachedStableState`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscxmlstatemachine.html#reachedStableState) signal.

```
// We declared a QTestEventLoop as m_eventLoop
connect(stateMachine, &QScxmlStateMachine::reachedStableState, 
        &m_eventLoop, &QTestEventLoop::exitLoop);

stateMachine->submitEvent("MyEvent");
m_eventLoop.enterLoopMSecs(3000);
// check the state, results etc
```