# How to use Qtest to test a QT statemachine workflow

Tags: c++, qt, state-machine, qtestlib, scxml

I'm trying to implement a QT state machine based workflow, and for testing purpose, I'm tring to play my workflow using QTest.

```
void initTestCase()
{    

    machine = loadScxmlFile("StateMachine.scxml");
    machine->start();

    auto wrapper = new Wrapper(machine);
    wrapper->connect();

    qDebug() << "machinestate" << wrapper->getmachineState();
    qDebug() << "activeStateBefore" << wrapper->getmachineState();
    wrapper->initialize();
    qDebug() << "activeStateAfter" << wrapper->getmachineState();
}
```

But sadly, even if I load my scxml properly, and even if it looks running and initialized, the active_state is always empty.

```
Config: Using QtTest library 5.9.0, Qt 5.9.0 (x86_64-little_endian-llp64 shared (dynamic) release build; by MSVC 2015)
QDEBUG : TestXImagerMock::initTestCase() machinestate ()
QDEBUG : TestXImagerMock::initTestCase() activeStateBefore ()
QDEBUG : TestXImagerMock::initTestCase() activeStateAfter ()
PASS   : TestXImagerMock::initTestCase()
```

When I try to use a proper QCoreApplication everything looks like a charm so it seems the problem comes from the QTEST_MAIN

```
QCoreApplication testapplication(argc, nullptr);
testapplication.exec();
```

gives

```
QDEBUG : TestXImagerMock::initTestCase() onEntry_NotInitialized
QDEBUG : TestXImagerMock::initTestCase() onEntry_NotInitialized
QDEBUG : TestXImagerMock::initTestCase() onEntry_Initializing
```

but thoses logs comes after the `testapplication.exec()` was called.

Do I need to add something to have the same behaviour in the QCoreApplication created by QTest?

Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test Qts SCXML state machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40677999/how-to-test-qts-scxml-state-machines)

Comment: indeed when I force the QCoreApplication::processEvents() the event are processed.
but is this a proper solution?

Comment: AFAIK, without an event loop running, you'll never see the state machine progress through its states, so you'll need to do that or something similar.